# How can I make the particular trail longer in After Effects CS4?

Tags: video, after-effects

How can I make the particular trail longer?

Why when I animate the particular do I only have a trail when I parent it to an Object or Emitter?

Comment: You need to add more information to your question.  For starters, what software are you using?

Comment: after effects cs4

Answer (score 2):

You need to change lifespan of the particle and move the emitter around.  The longer the lifespan of the particle the longer the trail will be because the trail is composed of ageing particles.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the previous answer. You could also add Wind or Turbulence in order to make the "tail" blow further away from the emitter.